# Change password in headless mode

Tags: shell, ubuntu, io-redirection, password

I am building a script to fully automate a VPS setup, and I need to change the root password. I would like to avoid typing it as the script is running through SSH.

Is there a way to redirect an arbitrary value to the input of `passwd` command?

**EDIT**

I know for `passwd < passwd_file.txt` containing the password twice... I would like to know if there is a more elegant way as it seems a little bit clumsy to use a temp file for this purpose.

Comment: Why not just set a disabled password `usermod -p '*' root`, and setup SSH key-based authentication?

Comment: I would like to keep a (strong) password to be able to log from another user.

Comment: expect also works for may things

Comment: I finally found the solution: see below...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't say what version of UNIX you're using, but on Linux the passwd(1) man page shows:

```
   --stdin
          This option is used to indicate that passwd should read the  new
          password from standard input, which can be a pipe.
```

So all you have to do is run:

```
echo 'somepassword' | passwd --stdin
```

Edit to add: more portable is `chpasswd` which exists on (at least) both Red Hat and Ubuntu:

```
echo 'someuser:somepassword' | chpasswd
```

See the man page.

Comment: I would have been really fond of this option, but it does not exists on Ubuntu... :-(

Comment: You can use chpasswd.  That exists on both Red Hat and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have a tough time doing what you want.  The `passwd` command goes to great lengths to avoid just the situation you describe, so as to hinder any password guessing schemes, and circumvent a lot of potential security problems.

Can you use the `useradd` command?  Typical linux `useradd` has a "-p" or "--password" option that lets you set the *encrypted* password to some value.  You can get that encrypted password out of the file `/etc/shadow`.

The other option is to monkey with the file `/etc/shadow`.  It shouldn't be too hard to used `sed` or something to change the salted, encrypted root password.

Comment: First, thanks for your quick reply. But `useradd` is not recommended, man pages says I should prefer `adduser`... And second option is yet worst than mine... ;-P

Comment: @MikeAski, On many systems `adduser` is simply a front-end to `useradd`.  For general interactive usage, the `adduser` command is preferred since it usually has a number of useful defaults.  From a script `useradd`, or in this case `usermod` is potentially a valid choice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Found the way. `printf` saved me:

```
HOST=...
echo "Root password? " && read -r ROOT_PASSWORD
...
ssh root@$HOST <<EOF
    printf "$ROOT_PASSWORD\n$ROOT_PASSWORD\n" | passwd
EOF
```

That is to me the best way out: clean & perfectly secure as password never get on local nether remote host in clear (through ssh connection only).

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap tmux around passwd:

```
tmux new-session -ds chpwd passwd
tmux send-keys -t chpwd NEWPASSWORD$'\n'
tmux send-keys -t chpwd NEWPASSWORD$'\n'
```

Run as root of course.